# jQuery - Number formatting causing calculations to break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying different number formatting plugins, currently this one: https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number/

Unfortunately they seem to break my calculations due to the commas within the `.val()`. I've put together the following jsfiddle as a demonstration of what one of the calculations look like. You will notice with this test that if the numbers in the user value field is less than four digits the calc works, once it goes over then it breaks.

Example of the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/WnryF/

Note: In my application, I don't actually write  to the `input`, I wrote to only those that contain a specific data attr, but it does need to be global.

Comment: It still seems to be working fine. Although I recommend getting elements more standarly: `$(multiplier)` -> `$(".multiplier")`

Comment: What the heck, it wasn't working a little while ago. So odd.

Comment: Maybe you were changing the actual field on the HTML page and not the value of the element?

Comment: Pretty much. I got the error to repeat. Change the value in the first input then leave the input, it will not update. 

What I need is that the calculation updates when the user changes values in the fields.

Comment: Sorry, change the value of the first input and the number more be 4 digits or longer.

Comment: That's because that information is not saved when you click "Run" on the page. How about we make a run button that will run the information through the function and update the answer?

Comment: Two things, one I don't want the user to have to click a run button, that's poor UX for this app. Second, if you disable the `.number` function then the `.change` will update whenever either of the two input fields are updated as you can see with how the calculation function is written.